# Custom inputAccessoryView doesn't show up in iPad simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'm trying to implement custom inputAccessoryView. Everything works well in iPhone, but when I run in iPad Simulator these vars even aren't called:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView?
{
    return self.containerView;
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool
{
    return true;
}
```

What is the difference between iPad and iPhone environment?